# Built in camera not working in ubuntu 22.10 + Dell 14 N4050

Tags: drivers, dell, camera

when i open cheese or another camera application like guvcview it didn't respond and ask me to force quit it. But my camera light is on.Please solve this...

```
lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:643e Microdia Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro XM102K Optical Wheel Mouse
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```